# Make <a href> tag downloadable by passing a variable?

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

How can I pass a java variable to a  tag and make it downloadable ? I have tried the below code. But unfortunately it opens the file,  rather than downloading it.

```
 out.println("<a href=" + path + ">" + fileName + " download</a>" + "<BR>");
```

Please follow the full code,

```
 while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("location"));
                path = rs.getString("location");
                fileName = rs.getString("fileName");
                out.print(path + "<BR>");
                out.println("<a href=" + path + ">" + fileName + " download</a>" + "<BR>");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server need to send the respnose header `Content-Disposition` when you click on that link.

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="picture.png"
```

Answer (score 4):

The latest chrome(from 65) disabled download file which is not same origin with the site you visit. Before chrome 65 you can download the file just add download attribute to `<a>` tag.

The commit link is https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/2a6afcb26ba6cd2324ddaa366b11968237e304a3%5E%21/#F0

So if you still want to download the file, the link you request should return response header

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.ext`